# changing a trained static input shape to dynamic shape in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have trained my MobileNetV3Small with 2 dense layers and got my result. but I set 640,480,3 as my input shape and now I need to test some images with different sizes. as it starts with convolution layers size must not matter. but I received errors as it requires its defined size (640,480,3) and padding and resizing didn't perform well. so I want to change the input shape to (None, None,3) without retraining it from scratch. It took 3 days to train my model and I don't want to train it again to change the input size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try this on your `Keras.Model` instance:

```py
model.input.set_shape((None, None, 3))
```

Comment: that brought up some problems but it worked in the end. Thank you